# Deploy a (portable) database Java server application

Tags: java, database, portability

I have a "basic" Java app that works somewhat like a server (listens to certain ports).

I want to add a database to the project so that I can interact with certain tables based on the data from the listened ports (basic operations - no alien-technology.

I am looking for a solution to implementing the database into the project so that there is no need of any "help" from outside of the app.In the end resulting and a "portable" app, that can be ran from other operating systems without any prerequisites (installing different services, etc).

I have seen solutions like H2, implementing MySQL services (way too complicated for what I need),Java GO, but I need something far less complicated, like C# and database connection to an Microsoft Acces database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into `JavaDB` or `SQLite`. Both can be embedded into your application, and can be run fully in memory (no persistence at all) or backed up by files.

Comment: In addition to this correct answer, check out Java Embedded Suite if you are working with a memory constraint device.